# Angular: Trying to synchronize between 2 functions that I have in service

Tags: angular

I have 2 functions that work individually
But I want to synchronize between them working together.

One function **getRandomNumbers** - Whose role is displayed every second at a random number between 1 and 20

Second function **up** - Button that allows me to change the number of **getRandomNumbers**
At the push of a button the number will advance by +1

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-njsc7p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Felevator.service.ts)

My code:

Service:

```
export class ElevatorService {

  floor = new BehaviorSubject<number>(3);
  floorNumber: number = -1;

  constructor() {
    this.floor.next(1);
  }

  getRandomNumbers() {
    return interval(1000).pipe(
      map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1),
      tap((res) => (this.floorNumber = res))
    );
  }


  up() {
    const floor = this.floor;
    floor.pipe(
        take(1),
        filter((v) => v < 20),
        map((v) => v + 1),
        tap((res) => (this.floorNumber = res))

      )
      .subscribe((v) => this.floor.next(v));
      return floor;
  }
```

My component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  floor = new BehaviorSubject<number>(3);
  Count = 0;
  buttonsDisabled: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Count++;
    this.elevatorService.getRandomNumbers().subscribe(this.floor);
  }
  elevatorServiceFloorValue$ = this.elevatorService.floor;

  constructor(private elevatorService: ElevatorService) { }

  up() {
    this.elevatorService.up();
  }
```

My component.html:

```
<input type="button" value="Up" (click)="up()" />

<div class="elevator">
  <pre class="floor">{{ this.floor | async }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this homework or something? I have seen similar code to this a couple of times now. If it is, it is very confusing homework, and I would get my course material elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep the state in the service and push that state to a subject:

```js
floorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
floorNumber: number = 0;

get floor() {
   return this.floorSubject.asObservable()
}
```

You also had a reference to a count in your component, similar to some other users question I just had a look at. I removed it because it wasn't used in any meaningful way.

I made it so you just have to subscribe to `getNumbers` for it to start pushing random values to that same subject.

Here's the whole fix for your code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtk8c4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)